# Help with HMAC Known plaintext / mac puzzle

Tags: hmac, attack

Finally caving and asking for help...I'm not in the field, just doing random CTF challenges to learn more and I've really been enjoying it in general. However, I'm totally stuck on this puzzle at the moment. If you see the answer, please don't tell me but please just give a bit of a hint or something.

### Here's what I know:

- a plaintext message: msg = "helloworld"
- it's associated hmac = hextstring =  HMAC(256 bit random key, "helloworld")
- I know the key was generated with Mersenne Twister via getrandbits() in Python
- I know it was seeded using system time, not /dev/urandom
- The goal is: change the plaintext and send it back with associated mac to pass verification ("helloworld" --> "helloadmin")

### Here's what I assumed:

- My only hope is to find the 256 bit key somehow. I assumed this based on (1) I read that HMAC is resistant to extension attacks (I tried that anyway assuming md5 but it didn't work) and (2) given the problem states the getrandbits / dev/urandom detail, I think it's got to do with the seed.

I don't know the actual hash function, but I think it's MD5 based on it having previously been the default for python's HMAC (it's an old challenge) and the size of the hash (I could be completely wrong though).

### Here's what I'm thinking / trying etc:

Given that I know python's getrandbits has been seeded with system time and not /dev/urandom, I read the python source, and figured out exactly how it's seeded. I'm trying to brute force possible seeds values, starting at now as the system time and going backwards. The issue is it's not really "just" the system time that it uses, it uses system time, monotonic time, and pid together to seed it when there's no /dev/urandom. In other words, the space of reasonable seed values is still pretty big. I also don't know how many times it's been called after seeding, so I'm still thinking this is the wrong approach, because it's possible a got the seed right, and if they've called it just twice post seed I would have missed it already.

I'm thinking that it might be related to MT being crackable - but if I could get the 624 values I would need to collect to crack it, I would also know the secret key and be done...

I also tried a timing attack and an extension attack, but no luck.

Any suggestions would be welcome, it's driving me nuts.

EDIT (1/16/24): still no progress on this. I was able to get python building locally, and so hacked it to follow the system time initialization path, logged the generated seeds, and then confirmed that I was properly building the seed in the 'attack' script (I wasn't). The time python uses is a 64 bit in nanoseconds, and I was also adding the bits in the wrong order. Once I sorted that out, I confirmed that I was able to manufacture the same seed that Python would make on it's own in the case with no system source of entropy available, but still no dice. I guess theré's something I don't see as I don't think they would expect a brute force solution with such a large search space.

EDIT (3/13/24) - finally solved!

Comment: How large is that seed in the end? Is it possibly 32 bits? Are you sure it didn't just use system time, as it is an old challenge? How big is the MAC? If it is 16 bytes then you can assume it is MD5, 20 bytes for SHA-1 etc.

Comment: I also thought they might have just used system time for the challenge, so I tried that too, just counting down from now to 0 a second at a time, but unfortunately that hasn't done it. The MAC is 16 bytes, so I guess hopefully that means it's MD5. Python uses 5 unit32s  (this part is in c) to seed the MT PRNG in the case where there's no /dev/urandom - the first 8 coming from the system time, the next 4 from the pid and the last 8 from monotonic time: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_randommodule.c#L263 (If I"m understanding correctly)

Comment: Also I should add (will add to description if it seems relevant) - the way the challenge is set up, I can hit an endpoint and get issued new data, which in this case is only a new MAC, same msg, etc. So I could in theory collect however many I needed - though I'm assuming they're reseeding and each time (it's like reissuing the challenge).

Comment: Well, it may also be that you should be try to reconstruct the state of the Mersenne twister if not enough info is given w.r.t. to the actual seeding used. Trying to hone in on the time and then assuming a low PID seems a good initial way of cracking things though.

Comment: Thanks, that's at least a bit reassuring - was hoping that there's not some attack I just haven't read about yet. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Well, a quick look indicates that the tempering function inside of the twister can be reversed to get the state... I didn't mention that *directly*.

Comment: I haven't worked through reversing MT to get the state (but doing that next to learn) - Though - I don't see how I could do that here? We need 624 consecutive rng outputs to reproduce the state, but I can only get macs (maybe gen'd with same seed, unknown).

This is the POC of I'm trying to perform, here I gave the seed though, for the other system it's obviously seeded with sys time, pid, monotonic time so it's a little more complicated. https://github.com/heathhenley/CryptoPals/blob/main/set3/same_attack_python_mt.py  

Might have to put this one down for a bit until I know more lol

Comment: You are overcomplicating it, been there also :) but I can confirm the solution can be computed on a laptop within a few seconds. I would recommend checking the history ;)